# How to change images in a Tab in TabLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt, styling

At the moment I have a TabLayoutPanel where there is an image URL in the  tags of my UiBinder for the Panel. Is there a way for an image to be swapped out once a tab is selected, using UiBinder? If not, how would I go about doing that in CSS? Is this at all possible?

Thanks.

```
<g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="homePanel" barUnit='PX' barHeight='100'>
        <g:tab>
        <g:header> 
            <img src = "images/sprites_01.png"></img> 
        </g:header>
        <g:Label>Hello, world!</g:Label>
        </g:tab>
        <!-- First Tab -->
        <g:tab>
        <g:header>
            <img src = "images/sprites_02_notselected.png"></img>
        </g:header>
            <my:FirstTabWidget ui:field="TabWidgetOne">    </my:FirstTabWidget>
        </g:tab>
```

etc...

Comment: It is possible by selecting the element of the tabs (using the `ui:field` property) and then doing the swap using a [SelectionHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/SelectionHandler.html). Please paste your `.ui.xml` file so I can make a proper answer.

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan, added some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.ui.xml` file, put a `ui:field` property in your img elements:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="homePanel" barUnit='PX' barHeight='100'>
        <g:tab>
            <g:header> 
                <img ui:field="tab1Img" src = "images/sprites_01.png"></img> 
            </g:header>
            <g:HTML>My first tab</g:HTML>
        </g:tab>
        <g:tab>
            <g:header>
                <img ui:field="tab2Img" src = "images/sprites_02_notselected.png"></img>
            </g:header>
            <g:HTML>My second tab</g:HTML>
        </g:tab>
    </g:TabLayoutPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

and in your code, access those elements:

```
@UiField ImageElement tab1Img;
@UiField ImageElement tab2Img;
```

Add a SelectionHandler in your TabLayoutPanel, and swap the image src attributes as desired:

```
homePanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>(){
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> evt){
        //change the img source here:
        tab1Img.setSrc("myOtherImage1.png");
        tab2Img.setSrc("myOtherImage2.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason every time I try to compile it's giving me a deferred binding error when I use ImageResource. Do you possibly have an idea for why that is happening? I do appreciate the help by the way-- I can see what you are going for and it makes sense.

Comment: In that case, try using `tab1Img.setSrc(myImageResource.getSafeUri());`.

Comment: There seems to be an error within <img ui:field="" src="">, so simply declaring that the image exists is throwing this error. Have you implemented this before?

Comment: Yes, but for that to work, your root element of the `ui.xml` must be a [HTMLPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html). So, in other words, your TabLayoutPanel must be a child of the HTMLPanel. I updated the example to reflect this.

Comment: I meant "root widget" not "root element"... The root element is of course the `<ui:UiBinder>` element.